# Prove $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt {-5}] $ is not a UFD without factoring?

Tags: ring-theory, factoring, alternative-proof, unique-factorization-domains

We know the ring $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] $ is not a UFD.

The typical proof is showing that $6$ factors in $2$ ways.

But there must be a better way to show this than to do trial and error factoring of some random element of the ring.

So how does one prove $ \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] $ is not a UFD without factoring a certain element ?

I can show it must be atomic and has a finite amount of units. But that is insufficient and perhaps even irrelevant ; UFD have that too.

Comment: Show that it's not a GCD domain, for example. i.e. find two elements such that the ideal generated by them is not principal.

Comment: But how do we do that without factoring ? Seems alot like factoring 6 to me.

Comment: Show that  $$I=\{a+b\sqrt{-5}\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Z}, a\equiv b\pmod2\}$$ is an ideal, and that it is not principal.

Comment: Ok but then we are factoring within modular arithmetic not ?

Comment: @mick it is "like" factorization, but it isn't factorization exactly. Meanwhile, I think that many of these concepts are related to each other.

Comment: In the title you say something, but in the question itself you say something way harsh: "There must be a **better way**" . Better....wrt what, or for whom? Showing the decomposition in two wasy of $\;6\;$ , say, looks to me as simple and "good" as one can expect...what do you mean by "better" here? And the element is not that random: doing a little arithmetic one gets with very simple elements the dcompositions!

Comment: It depends what background you allow. The method using a factorization of 6 has the advantage of being *simple*: it does not need a lot of machinery. You could instead show the ideal $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ is not principal: it is known that a Dedekind domain is a UFD iff it is a PID. But that requires a lot more work to justify (both proving the result and showing $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a Dedekind domain). The Dedekind property is crucial: $\mathbf Z[x]$ is a UFD and not a PID!

Comment: The idea is that 6 is a lucky Guess. Some elements may factor uniquely. And if we consider generalizing this UFD test to other rings or an infinite collection of rings , then we stumble upon The issue that we have no way to find The right elements to factor.

Comment: @mick so you're looking for a magic idea that tells you whether a ring is a UFD right away regardless of our knowledge about its elements? Isn't that too much to ask for? By the way, $6$ is not a lucky guess. In fact, you can show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-n}]$ is not a UFD for $n \geq 3$ (if I'm not mistaken) by analyzing $n$ or $n+1$ in this ring.

Comment: Suppose we had to factor 37 elements before 1 of them showed a non-Unique factorizarion , would that not be terrible ?

Comment: Well, life is terrible in general. Math is just one manifestation of this fact. :P

Comment: Again, $\,6\,$ is not that random. In $\;\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-n}]\;,\;\;n\in\Bbb N\;$,  I would go first precisely on $\;n+1\;$ . Why? because $$(1-\sqrt{-n})(1+\sqrt{-n})=1+n$$ Randomness doesn't work a lot in mahtematics.

Comment: @stressedout I think for $n = 3$ you get a Minkowski bound less than $2$.

Comment: Yes Antonio. That is a good reason. But what the ring is actually a UFD and you keep trying Numbers like k^2 + n without succes ?  Or what about if The ring is not a UFD but The first 31 values of k for k^2 + n do not give 2 distinct factorizations ??

Comment: Im not so familiar with the discriminant and the minkowsky bound. I googled them but it was too complicated for me.